# Падает сервер, как найти причину

Tags: python, lighttpd, django

Сайт:

- python(django)
- lighttpd
- postgresql

Сервере запускаю:

```
./manage.py runfcgi method=prefork maxrequests=20 maxspare=20 host=127.0.0.1 port=8881 pidfile=/tmp/server.pid
```

По началу было все хорошо, но вот иногда питон процессов становится на столько много что он поглощает всю ОЗУ(8Гб). И естественно что сайт ложится, и на сервере почти ничего сделать нельзя.

Пробовал разные установки запуска:

- maxspare
- minspare
- maxrequests

все эти значения перебирал, но не взирая на ограничения максимума потоков, он создает их и больше, пожирая тем самым всю память.

Может есть какой способ вычислить что его так нагружает, или может сервер атакуют, или код программный его так убивает?

Вообще раньше держал нагрузку 400 - 700 онлайн, не быстро грузил страницы (3-18с), но держал, теперь и при 30 - 100 начинает забивать ОЗУ, не всегда, но бывет.

Comment: Добавляли код который работает с thread и очередью Queue ?

Comment: Нет, даже не пойму о чем речь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, для начала посмотреть логи django - там видно какие вьюхи у тебя работают, какие ошибки, как часто их вызывают - таким образом подтвердится или отсечется ddos.
Второе - используется-ли многопоточность (а-ля Celery или что-нибудь самописное), мб некотнролируемый вызов задач, которые ушли в бесконечные циклы?
И наконец взять на заметку вот этот модуль: [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar), воспользоваться им и возможно найти узкие места.